# jquery .ajax call does not execute the success function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the jquery code to call a json web service.

```
    function getMajorGroups(){

    var element = $(".item-group-button");
    var response = $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"http://localhost:6458/posApplication/touch/getAllMajorGroupsForTouch",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data:{}
    });

    response.done(function(data){
        alert(data);
    });

    response.fail(function() {
        $("#item-groups").empty();
    });
}
```

I connect to a service in my localhost and the URL is as given above! When I remove the http:// the response.fail only runs. when I add the http:// both success or fail doesn't run. Is this method I've written is wrong or is there anything missing. I'm calling a JSON Web service here!

The webservice returns a JSON string when I try it in the browser! I'm calling a GET type service method.

Update :

this is the Json response when I directly use the URL in the browser.

```
{"majorGroups":[{"update":"false","hasMore":"false","status":"A","description":"Beverage","majorGroupId":"48","code":"Beverage"},{"update":"false","hasMore":"false","status":"A","description":"Laundry","majorGroupId":"51","code":"Laundry"},{"update":"false","hasMore":"false","status":"A","description":"Cigarette","majorGroupId":"50","code":"Cigarette"},{"update":"false","hasMore":"false","status":"A","description":"Food","majorGroupId":"47","code":"Food"},{"update":"false","hasMore":"false","status":"A","description":"Health Center","majorGroupId":"52","code":"Health Center"}],"failure":"false"}
```

Comment: Cross domain problems on localhost?

Comment: Use FireBug or Chrome Developer Tools (Ctrl+Shift+I), you can inspect request/response more clearly. I doubt on CORS (cross domain) issue though.

Comment: I'm new to Jquery + JSON web services so can you please explain a little bit!

Comment: Are you also downloading the page from localhost:6458?  It not, you have to use `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in the server response, or use JSONP.

Comment: I'm not downloading the page from localhost. It's just a html file with the necessary Jquery file. I think I'm having cross domain problems. further more, the service I'm accessing is developed using spring 2.5. Where should I add the Access-control-allow-origin code? is it in the web.xml file

Comment: Seems like there is nothing wrong with your JS code and expected JSON result, if you move expected JSON to a file say test.js and change url to point to test.js instead of webservice url, you can verify basic sanity. This rules out CORS issue as well, which is right since client and server both are under same domain (localhost). Possibly a server-side issue now related to webservice call

Comment: @DimalChandrasiri the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` field is an HTTP header.  I've no idea how you add one of those in Spring.

Answer (score 0):

While using dataType=json there is one probable issue which cause failure:

As per http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also rejected; the server should return a response of null or {} instead.

Another approach you could take is to use `.getJSON` function, see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/
Again take a note of (from `.getJSON` doc):

> Important: As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the request will usually fail silently...

On Firefox, add FireBug plugin and check Network tab.

Comment: I checked the response in the network tab and there was nothing in it!

Comment: To rule out resulting JSON format issue, can you post expected JSON response, see if you can print it at server side itself

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case the was caused because I was using a "date" from MySQL and something gets corrupted. I just needed to previously format that field and thats was it.